# Sql server issue ORDER BY clause is invalid in views

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here I am going to post my full stored procedure code then I will pick the area which is giving error.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[WarrantyTrends]
(
    @StartYr AS INT,
    @EndYr  AS INT  
)
AS
    DECLARE @query varchar(max)
    DECLARE @years varchar(max), @yearsColumns varchar(max)

    SELECT 1 mID, 'January' as month  into #tempMonths   UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2,'February' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3,'March' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4,'April' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5,'May' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6,'June' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 7,'July' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 8,'August' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 9,'September' as month     UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10,'October' as month    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 11,'November' as month    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 12,'December' as month  

    SELECT @years=COALESCE(@years+',','')   +'['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+']',
    @yearsColumns=COALESCE(@yearsColumns+',','')   +'isnull(['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+'],0) 
    as ['+cast(years as varchar(4))+']'
    from  (select distinct YEAR(CurDate) years from EOD_Main
    WHERE YEAR(CurDate)>=@StartYr AND YEAR(CurDate)<=@EndYr 
    ) as x

    SET @query = 'Select months,'+@yearsColumns+' from (
    select distinct mID, YEAR(CurDate)  years,[MONTH] months,  
    isnull(Warranty_Info,0) as Warranty_Info  from EOD_Main
          right join #tempMonths on datename(month,CurDate ) =[month] 
    ) as xx
    PIVOT 
    (
    SUM(xx.Warranty_Info) FOR years IN ('+@years+')
    )
    as pvt ORDER BY mID'
    PRINT @query
    --EXEC(@query)

   drop table #tempMonths
```

See this code

```
SELECT 
    @years = COALESCE(@years+',','')   +'['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+']',
    @yearsColumns = COALESCE(@yearsColumns+',','')   +'isnull(['+ cast(years as varchar(4))+'], 0) as ['+cast(years as varchar(4))+']'
FROM 
    (SELECT distinct YEAR(CurDate) years 
     FROM EOD_Main
     WHERE YEAR(CurDate) >= @StartYr AND YEAR(CurDate) <= @EndYr) as x
```

This inner most area

```
 (SELECT distinct YEAR(CurDate) years 
  FROM EOD_Main
  WHERE YEAR(CurDate) >= @StartYr AND YEAR(CurDate) <= @EndYr) as x**
```

I am not being able to order the year asc wise rather getting error.

In this area I want to generate year ascending wise.... so guide me what I can do. thanks

Comment: where you are putting order by

Answer (score 1):

Order by is irrelevant in views. You will not automatically get teh records inteh right order. YOu need to havea an order by in all the sql code you want ordered.

```
Order by year(curDate)
```

Comment: can u show me how can i order the year in ascending order. thanks

Comment: can u plzz rectify my sql...where to add the order by. thanks